# How to add a regression line to a TraMineR entropy plot?

Tags: r, traminer

I'd like to know if it's somehow implemented to add a linear regression line to a TraMineR entropy plot.

**Example:**

```
library(TraMineR)
data(biofam)
set.seed(10)
biofam <- biofam[sample(nrow(biofam),300),]
biofam.lab <- c("Parent", "Left", "Married", "Left+Marr",
                "Child", "Left+Child", "Left+Marr+Child", "Divorced")
biofam.seq <- seqdef(biofam, 10:25, labels=biofam.lab)

seqplot(biofam.seq, type="Ht")
```

I want something like this:

[image]

I know that I can calculate the entropy with `seqient()`

```
biofam$ient <- seqient(biofam.seq, with.missing=TRUE)
```

But since the data is in wide format I'm not sure how to grab the data so that I could do an `abline(lm(y ~ x))` approach.

```
> head(biofam[c(1, 10:12, 28)])
     idhous ... a15 a16 a17   ... Entropy
1234     NA   ... 0   0   0 ... 0.3010904
1515  86261   ... 0   0   0 ... 0.3154649
276   17561   ... 0   0   0 ... 0.4012026
1212  69021   ... 0   0   0 ... 0.5517478
153   11391   ... 0   0   0 ... 0.2559298
1164  66641   ... 0   0   0 ... 0.4178207
```

Also `seqplot()` does not seem to provide a numerical vector/matrix like `plot()`:

```
p <- plot(sin, -pi, 2*pi, sub="ordinary plot")
s <- seqplot(biofam.seq, type="Ht")

> str(p)
List of 2
 $ x: num [1:101] -3.14 -3.05 -2.95 -2.86 -2.76 ...
 $ y: num [1:101] -1.22e-16 -9.41e-02 -1.87e-01 -2.79e-01 -3.68e-01 ...

> str(s)
 NULL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cross-sectional entropy rendered by `seqHtplot` or `seqplot(..., type="Ht")` is stored in the `$Entropy` element of the object returned by `seqstatd`. The value at each time point is the entropy of the cross-sectional state distribution at this time point. So there is one value per time point.

This is different form the longitudinal entropy returned by `seqient`. Here there is one value per sequence. The value is the entropy of the state distribution within the sequence.

So, to plot the regression line you just need to extract the cross-sectional entropy using `seqstatd`, define the time variable, and use these variables in `abline(lm())`:

```
stat.bf <- seqstatd(biofam.seq)
ent <- stat.bf$Entropy
time <- 1:length(ent)

seqplot(biofam.seq, type = "Ht")
abline(lm(ent ~ time), col = "red", lty = 2)
```

[image]